# What folder should i put my production website into?

Tags: apache, web-hosting

I will be running 2 vhosts (dev and production). I'm thinking about creating 2 users (dev and prod) and directing apache to look into /home/dev/www and /home/prod/www. If I do this I will need to give apache the proper permissions to manage those folders.

Does this sound like a bad idea? Would it make more sense to just use /var/www/prod/ and var/www/dev ?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, it probably comes down to preference, but I think you should put them in `/var/www/prod/` and `/var/www/dev/` so that the sites are all in one place. If you need to back-up all of your sites, you know they are all in `/var/www`, and you could also make /var or /var/www its own mount point.

You can still create 2 users for dev and prod, just give them some sane rights for those directories. You can make them all owner, make apache the group, and aside from possibly logging, you wouldn't need to set `g+w` except in those instances.